# How to map keys in VsVim to Visual Studio commands?

Tags: visual-studio, keymapping, vsvim

Is it possible to map keys in VsVim to Visual Studio commands? For example, can I map `gb` to `View.NavigateBackward`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do it via your _vsvimrc file.

This should do the trick:

`nnoremap gb :vsc View.NavigateBackward<CR>`

You can even map extension commands, like those from Resharper:

`nnoremap gi :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoImplementation<CR>`

The full documentation is here:
https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/VsVim-Nonstandard-Behavior